# how to disable angularjs cache?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, cache-control

I am building a simple angularjs app to insert data into a table, but everytime i make any simple change i have to manually clear the browser cache for the change to show up, a refresh or hard refresh does not do it.

I searched for any solution and found this

```
app.run(function($rootScope,$templateCache) {
  $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
   $templateCache.removeAll();
  });
});
```

but did not work, can anybody point me to the right direction how to solve this problem.

Thank you,

Comment: `$templateCache.removeAll();` can harm if you are using `ui-bootstrap` or if  you have multiple tempalted inside the `$templateCache`

Comment: how can i stop angularjs caching problem , it's really frustrating to have to clear the cache everytime i do an update. And most of all, users wont know and cant clear their browser cache manually.

Comment: The angular cache has nothing to do with your problem. Every time you reaload the page, the application starts from scratch with an empty template cache. If you see an old template after a refresh, then it's either the browser or the server that caches the template. Not angular.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but the problem is i have a wordpress site on the same server and it updates fine only the new project which i am trying in angularjs has that problem. All i am doing is creating a simple login form. I tried it in firefox and chrome both with same results.

Comment: Did you solved this? I'm having the same issue, and I don't know what it is.

Comment: @iwannabaa : The problem was because my code was being called inside an iframe. I had to take out the iframe to solve my problem. I hope this helps.